# ASpNetCore 2.1 MVC redirecting on a JSON Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
<form asp-action="Login">
  <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This works fine in that when I submit it goes to my controller post method as expected.
 However, my issue is that for various reasons. I'm not allowed to redirect in the controller, but am returning a JSON object from the controller back to the view. At the moment, the JSON just gets thrown onto the page. What do I need to change on my code above to force the post back to run a javascript function?

Comment: You need to post the form using ajax if you want to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you could try something like this. 
As Stephen suggested, you need to be posting back to your controller using Ajax. I'll tie my example to jQuery (as you probably already have access to it).

Note: this is a simple example and I'm making some assumptions

```
<form id="frmLogin" asp-action="Login">
  <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //you could do some validation here/trigger unobtrusive validation
            if(("#frmLogin").valid()) {
                var data = $("#frmLogin").serialize();
                //assumption: your controller action accepts the form/object as a param called 'data'
                $.post("/yourcontroller/youraction", { data : data }, function(response) {
                     //this is just an example...if your JSON had a boolean 'success' element you could check it like so...
                     if(response.success) {
                         //do something
                     }
                     else {
                         //display an error
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```